# p:commandButton doesn't work on second page using lazyload in dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable working very well with LazyDataModel. It has a commandButton, that open a report for each row:

On the first page it works fine, but when I page change ( for example, go to page 2) commandButton missed the controls.

The report should open in a new page.

Source of command button:

```
<p:column style="width:30px; text-align:center;" headerText="Texto">
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.print}" immediate="true"
    title="View report" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'">           
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form"></f:ajax>                         
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{obj}" target="#{bean.myObject}"/>                         
</p:commandButton>
```

On the second page instead of opening the report , it just gives a new _blank page with the jsf page in the page 1. The report didn't show.

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disabling ajax on the `p:commandButton` and then adding an `f:ajax`. That is one of the weirdest constructions I've ever seen. Why? Please read [ask] and create a normal example and in [mcve] format (see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score -1):

add the form component to commandButton

```
<p:column style="width:30px; text-align:center;" headerText="Texto">
<h:form>
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.print}" immediate="true"
    title="View report" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'">           
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form"></f:ajax>                         
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{obj}" target="#{bean.myObject}"/>                         
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Why? What is the advantage or reason to do this? See my comment on the question. The construction in thequestion is weird to begin with.

Comment: so you can use a first property of the datatable to fix your current number page.because on the second page the commandButton can't remenber the form .

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean... totally. And you have the same weird (not used by **anyone**)  constructs in your code. Embedding a form in a column makes it even weirder. I've never ever seen anyone use it that way

Comment: i m trying helping you.for the "form" you cant put it where you want.check all the properties datatable and we will find a property named "first" and use it .

Comment: No you can't put the form anywhere you want. There are constraints. e.g. forms cannot be nested, so if the datatable needs to be in a form to (for having lots of inputs) or if filtering is needed with inputs that need to be in a form, having an additional form in a column cannot work...

Comment: i use 2 "form " in  my jsf page and it work fine.try it and try the first property.

Comment: I'm not saying you cannot use two forms, I'm saying that you can't put it anywhere you want. Maybe you should improve the answer so it is clear how to do it and the consequences. Including the 'and use the first property'... How? Where? When? There is no first property in your answer, nor in the question.

Comment: Oh, and btw, you are not helping 'me'... I'm not the poster of the question. I'm just a guy that is in this case playing 'pita' on getting better quality in questions and answers.

Answer (score -1):

`<p:dataTable id="dtform"  widgetVar="dtform"

                                 value="#{managedBeans.lazyModel}" 
                                 var="form" 
                                 paginator="true" 
                                 emptyMessage="#{message.ListeVide}"

                                 rows="10" 
                                 rowKey="#{form.id}"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                                 paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" 
                                 selectionMode="single"

                                 first="#{managedBeans.first}"
                                 lazy="true" > <p:ajax event="page" process="@this"   listener="#{managedBeans.onPageChange}" />`

```
    protected int first=0;
    public int getFirst() {  
       return first;  
  }  
  public void setFirst(int first) {  
       this.first = first;  
  }  
  public void onPageChange(PageEvent event) {  
       this.setFirst(((DataTable) event.getSource()).getFirst());  


  }  `
```

Comment: Hi, it's me again... Just code without any 'explanation' on why it is the asnwer is not a good answer. Please improve it.